# Operating System for first production windows server code?

Tags: .net, windows-server

I'm getting ready to purchase a server for me to deploy my first windows based (C# .NET) application but I'm not familiar with using windows for hosted applications.  I have the choice of the following versions of windows:

- Windows Server 2003
- <del>Windows Server 2003 Web</del>
- Windows Server 2003 Enterprise
- Windows Server 2008
- <del>Windows Server 2008 Web</del>
- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise

Would one of these be better for deploying a C# .NET application?

EDIT:
There will be 3 applications deployed but each will basically be the same, they will be services that are driven from data being brought in from a website that will likely run on the same server.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-roles.aspx

Comment: Need more info - what are you deploying? web application? Hosting the software distribution? Backend database for thick client?

Comment: There you go, hope thats enough info.

Comment: Seems that the Web edition will not do what is needed so thats no longer an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you meet the [requirements for Server 2008 Web](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-web-server.aspx), you should use that, because that is the [cheapest](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/pricing.aspx).  I would go with 2008 over 2003 because of IS.

Per edits:  Since you've crossed out Web versions, I would go with 2008 Standard unless I needed some [feature of Enterprise or Datacenter](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-features.aspx).

By the way, if you have an MSDN license, you can run any version of Server 2008 in a testing or staging capacity under that license.  You can use that license to determine whether or not a particular version will be right for your application. Then, once you deploy to production, you pay your normal license fees for the version you chose.

Comment: Actually it's nice because I have licenses for each here from a former job as a consultant, so I can play with them localy but there are things that I may not notice, like if there is a specific gotcha that I'm not aware of.

Comment: There aren't really any gotcha's.  If you need things like failover clusters (enterprise) or gobs and gobs of memory (datacenter) you should be fine with standard.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need huge amounts of memory, I'd suggest Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am sure you dont need the enterprise editions as you are only running 3 web applications and maybe some backend DB CRUD operations.

That leaves us 2003 or 2008 Standard Editions.

Now it comes down to how you feel. Forgive this list if I missed anything major!

**2003 PROS:**

- Proven Track Record
- Known Vunerabilities (I am sure more could be found....)
- IIS6

**2003 CONS:**

- 5 Years old
- Nearing end of life
- Need to Ensure is SP2 (R2 SP2 is even better)
- Needs more work securing with default settings

**2008 PROS:**

- Enhanced Security (I am sure more vunerabilities will be found....)
- More locked down with default settings
- IIS7
- Native .NET 3.5 support
- SP2 now RTM

**2008 CONS:**

- New Operating System
- New code base
- Vista based UI (put as a con as some people dont like, wait till they try 2k8 R2!)

I would opt for **2008 Standard Edition** as that is a stategic decision for the future.

NOTE: You can expand on this list I just added quickly off the top of my head

Answer (score -1):

**Linux+Mono** if your C# is at their supported level. It is free.

**disclaimer**: I advocate.

Comment: That is not an option, although I would prefer it, I currently have several Debian servers.  -1 because this question was specifically asking about windows servers.

Comment: Which is why I disclaimed ... I don't know :P